# How can I get write access to the API?

Tags: java, stackexchange-api

When trying to set writing access in the scope I receive the application need permission

```
webView.loadUrl("https://stackoverflow.com/oauth/dialog?client_id=19361&redirect_uri=https://stackexchange.com/oauth/login_success&scope=no_expiry,private_info,read_inbox,write_access");
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
    @Override
    public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
        if(url.contains("https://stackexchange.com/oauth/login_success#access_token=")){
            String code=url.replace("https://stackexchange.com/oauth/login_success#access_token=","");
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("accessToken",code);
            startActivity(intent);

        }
        System.out.println(url);
        super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
    }
});
```

Comment: you should create a stack app and the app should have write acess.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create any post on stackapps and set his url into stackapps post field

Answer (score 0):

In order to get an access token with the `write_access` scope, you need a Stack Apps post.

After [registering](https://stackapps.com/apps/oauth/register) your application on StackApps and obtaining an API key and a client id, in the "Stack Apps Post" field you should enter the link to a question you have asked.

If you have already registered your app, go to ["Manage your applications"](https://stackapps.com/apps/oauth), select the respective application, scroll to the bottom, click "Edit this app", then enter your question link in the "Stack Apps Post" field. Then, submit your changes.

See **[My app has to be published first? But it's still under development](https://stackapps.com/q/4573)**.